# C++ How do I to put this constructor in a cpp file?

Tags: c++, constructor, refactoring

I have a constructor in the `.h` file

```
C(std::string s = "",int i = 0,double d = 1)
{
    dataMember1 = s;
    dataMember2 = i;    
    dataMember3 = d;
}
```

If you provide the values of the string, int and double it will use those values, however without them, it will use the default ones. My question is how to refactor this so that I put it in a `.cpp` file.

When not refactoring it works fine for example if I declare

`C object1("object1", 0, 1), object2;` it will work, however if I refactor, the `object2` will cause a compile error saying that I don't have a `C()` constructor

Comment: This should be covered in any introductory C++ book.

Comment: what is the name of this constructor then?

Comment: @lost: constructors don't have names.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf copy constructor is a counterexample to your statement

Comment: @lost: oh you mean general kind of constructor. that sounds like a homework question. i suggest that you research it, since that's the usual idea of homework. but regarding *names*, as in function names, the standard explicitly states that constructors don't have names. modulo spelling (you can look it up) that's a direct quote from the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class C{
    public:
    C(string a= "" , int foo=1, char bar=0);
};

C::C(string a, int foo, char bar){ // this can go into a .cpp file
    cout<<a<<foo<<bar;
}


int main() {
    C c("hi",1,'T');
    return 0;
}
```

[On IDEone](http://ideone.com/9pTekL) .

But as others stated you should even just Google for ["C++ tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial)"(actually deals with something similar in *classes* chapter) or [read a book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C++_Programming_Language). It'll be a lot frustrating,faster and fulfilling...

Answer (score 1):

In your header put e.g.

```
struct C
{
    C( std::string s = "", int i = 0, double d = 1 );
};
```

In your implementation file, put

```
C::C( std::string s, int i, double d )
    // Memory initializer list here, if applicable.
{
    // whatever
}
```

Repeating the default value specifications in the implementation file, would be an error.

Remember to add the implementation file to your project, if you're using an IDE, or to compile and link it if you're working in the command line.